# Represent $x^n + x^{n−1}y + x^{n−2}y^2 + \dots + xy^{n−1} + y^n$ as $\sum_{i=1}^k g_i(x)h_i(y)$

Tags: calculus, functions, polynomials

**Problem**. Given a natural number $n$, consider the function
$$
f_n(x, y) = x^n + x^{n−1}y + x^{n−2}y^2 + \dots + xy^{n−1} + y^n
$$
of two real variables. Find the minimal number $k$ for which there exist functions $g_1, \dots , g_k, h_1, \dots , h_k$
of one real variable such that
$$
f_n(x, y) =
\sum_{i=1}^k
g_i(x)h_i(y)
$$

**Attempt 1**. So the first idea is just write
$$
f_n(x, y) = \frac{x^{n+1} - y^{n+1}}{x - y} = \frac{x^{n+1}}{x - y} - \frac{y^{n+1}}{x - y}
$$
but how to combine variables here I don't know. I even don't know how to decompose $x^2 + xy + y^2$ like a shorter sum.

**Attempt 2**. 
$$
f_n(x, y) = x^n + xy\cdot f_{n-2}(x, y) + y^n.
$$
So we need at least $2$ terms $+$ number of terms for $f_{n-2}(x, y)$. If this is true then we need at least $n$ summands. But it seems not ture.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the obvious
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n x^k\,y^{n-k}?
$$

Comment: The monomials $(1,x,x^2,...,x^n)$ are linearly independent functions. Any combination to less terms would contradict the fact that also the monomials $(1,y,y^2,...,y^n)$ are linearly independent functions.

Comment: So can you shed some light?